# Where can I find references to the theory behind PBC library?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this type of question. Anyway, I'm using PBC library for a project, but I'm a very newbie for what concerns pairing based cryptography. Then I ask some good references for Elliptic Curves Cryptography, possibly with some theory about groups or abstract algebra in general. I know this question has already been asked but I ask one thing more that I couldn't find: the theory behind the `pairing_apply`, in other words I'd like to know what is a pairing from a theoretical perspective. Where can I find some good explanation of this? On "traditional" books I couldn't find such a thing

Comment: There's an entire [doctoral thesis](https://crypto.stanford.edu/pbc/thesis.html) on implementing that library. I'm sure between that and the sources referenced by it you should get the answer to all your questions.

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thanks. Do you deem it suffient for a medium level of knowledge about this topic?